# What is creating a folder named ".mediaartlocal" in all my music folders?

Tags: files, music

I was looking through my music collection while hidden files were shown, and I noticed that almost every directory/album has a folder in it named `mediaartlocal`, which contains a jpg file with an album cover thumbnail, having a name such as:

```
 album-04594560ae5c3bbc152fbfde3adfd187-3386aee33491e940685b7aacf3efa852.jpeg
```

about 40K size.

It might be from Google's play music app, to perhaps locally cache the album covers, mainly because it's the only app I can think of that might want to do this kind of thing.  But before I delete them all, I'd like to know where they come from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think these files were created using the [Gnome Media Art Storage Spec.](https://live.gnome.org/MediaArtStorageSpec)

Applications like Banshee use this protocol to store cover art/thumbnails for music and other media files.  I don't know if Google Music uses this or not, but its a good possibility.

Comment: I just did a find on my music folder, and there are no new copies, so it must not be anything I'm using now.  It's possible it was created when I uploaded files to Google Music - I'll check next time I do that.

Answer (score 2):

Clementine just created those folders in my collection.

Comment: Looking at invalid [Clementine bug #3714](https://github.com/clementine-player/clementine/issues/3714), no, Clementine doesn't do that. It must rather be some GNOME process or maybe Tracker.